# Migrating/Convert Enterprise Jenkins to community version

Tags: jenkins

I have an enterprise jenkins and I wish to convert it to community jenkins version as I am not using any enterprise plugins.

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [post](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203601204-Uninstalling-Jenkins-Enterprise-FAQ).

You will either need to

1. Uninstall some plugins; and / or
2. Swtich out Jenkins.war